# manコマンドで表示されるマニュアルのバージョン、と実際のバージョンについて

Tags: linux, centos

**試したこと**
・`man grep`した結果表示されるバージョンと、`grep --version`結果が不一致でした
・`man sed`した結果はバージョン明記されていなかったので、`sed --version`結果と一致しているか確認出来ませんでした

---

**Q1.manコマンドで表示される内容は、あくまでも代表的なバージョンのマニュアルですか？**

---

**Q2.Linuxコマンドをバージョンアップした場合は、普通どうするのですか？**

・`man Linuxコマンド`のバージョンを何とかして上げる？(もしくはman内容も自動的にアップデートされる？？)
・manに対しては何もしない(manではなく、`Linuxコマンド`自体のドキュメントを参照する？)
・人それぞれ？

---

**環境**
・CentOS

Comment: 手元の CentOS 7.4 の場合では version 2.20 で一致しています。man page は `man-pages` パッケージに含まれています。(`yum info man-pages`)

Comment: 英語のmanページ表示させてみたら、一致していました

Answer (score 1, accepted):

manで表示されるマニュアルはOSの基礎的なコマンドであれば「man-page」パッケージ、もしくは「個々のパッケージ内に付属」、「ドキュメントだけパッケージとして独立(git-manなど)」、対応はまちまちです。

また、ロケールの設定によってmanの表示も英語や日本語に切り替わるかと思いますが、マニュアルページの翻訳状況によっては
必ずしもコマンドの最新版とは一致していない場合があります(親切なマニュアルは最後に注記されています)。

Answer (score 1):

Man Page(?) として保存されている内容が表示されているだけです。

検索してみたら、 [manコマンドについて詳しくまとめました](https://eng-entrance.com/linux-command-man)

> カタログページは、標準では環境変数$MANPATHで指定されている場所に保存されている。

とありました。　(昔は、Man Pageと呼んでいた)
従って、実際に組み込まれているコマンドのHelpページではありません。

この内容の更新については、別に方法があったと思いますが、詳しい人にお願いします。

Answer (score 0):

**A1**

通常、CentOSのようなLinuxディストリビューションは rpmやdebといったパッケージでソフトを管理しています。そしてrpmやdebに含まれるmanファイルがmanページとして表示されます。
そのため、配布元または開発元がmanファイルを含めているため、古いmanページがはいっていることもあります。また日本語のmanページは内容が古いことがあります。

**A2**

パッケージを更新した場合、通常新しいパッケージにmanページがあれば自動的に更新されます。